# power program from the book "c program. lang." version2, cycle

Tags: c, cycle

I am stuck with this line of the code from the "C Programming Language" book - 
"**for (p = 1; n > 0; --n)**" - the counter runs from 1 to more than 1, while step is -1. but what is the counter? n itself?

(I used to see **for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)**-like structures, so the issue of counter was clear, however in version 2 I encountered that I don't really know what and where the counter is...

From here:

```
/* power:  raise base to n-th power; n >= 0; version 2 */
   int power(int base, int n)
   {
       int p;
       for (p = 1; n > 0; --n)
           p = p * base;

       return p; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration `n` decrements by `1` because of `--n`, when `n` decrease  to `0` condition `n > 0` becomes false and loop breaks.

```
for (p = 1; n > 0; --n)
              ^
              |  When n = 0, condition becomes 0 > 0 that is false
```

In loop you are multiply `p = p * base;`  evaluates **=>** `base * base * base * ...n times` **=>** base<sup>n</sup>.

`p` is is for store result at the end p = base<sup>n</sup>.

You may like to write it like (a small code, I think bit fast too):

```
int p;
for (p = 1; n--  && (p*=base) ;)
return p;
```

**Edit:**  comments & answers:

> `for (p = 1; n > 0; --n)` - **when the counter starts?**

Yes `n` is counter, in for loop we don't need to initialized `n`. We just initializes `p` variable with `1` to store result. Value of `n` comes from function argument. you call your `int power(int base, int n);` function some where in main, like:

```
result = power(3,2);  // here base = 3, and n = 2
```

or

```
result = power(5,7); // here base = 5, and n = 7
```

> **from n to p (to 1)?**

Loop runs for `n` to `1` times (not condition is `> 0`) e.g
In first example when you call `power(3,2);`,  loop runs for `n` = `2` to `1`. 
likewise in second call of function `power(5,7);`  loop runs for `n` = `7` to `1`.

> **Why we need p here?**

As I have written above in my answer `p` we need to store result. e.g.

in loop `p` initially `1`, but in each iteration you multiply `p` with `base` value and store result back to `p` only. e.g.
for function call `power(3,2);` loop runs and `p` calculate like:

base = 3 , n = 2
p = 1;   // initialize

First iteration:

```
condition n > 0 is True because n is 2 (2 > 0). 
p = p * base = 1 * 3 = 3
and p becomes 3. 
Now --n decreases n to 1
```

Second iteration:

```
condition n > 0 is True because n is 1 (1 > 0). 
p = p * base = 3 * 3 = 9
and p becomes 9. 
Now --n decreases n to 0
```

third iteration:

```
condition n > 0 is False because n is 0 (0 > 0).  
condition false so loop breaks
```

return `p` that is 3<sup>2</sup> = `9`.

Comment: for (p = 1; n > 0; --n) - when the counter starts? from n to p (to1)? why we need p here?

Comment: Thank you for an expanded answer. Now I understand that p=0 is kind of declaration/initialization. Probably, when I get more experience I will understand it more...

Answer (score 1):

The initialisation in the `for` loop says `p = 1`, not `n = 1`. `n` is already provided as one of the function parameters, and serves as the counter. `p` is the accumulator for the result.

A clearer way to write this might be:

```
int p = 1;
while (n--) { p *= base; }
return p;
```

The moral here is that function parameters are already local variables, and there's no need to create a duplicate local variable just for the sake of it. It's perfectly fine to modify function parameters.

Comment: actually, I don't get how this cycle works - for (p = 1; n > 0; --n) - start from 1 to more than 1? or starts from n to more than p ?

Comment: @Ilan: `p`, not `n`. Read it again, carefully.

Comment: I see, but it does not help - what for we need p here? we start from n  to n>0. How can we start from p if it is the end point... Wow! I cannot get it

Comment: `p` is the accumulator. Do you know what the "power" function is supposed to do, and how it is defined?

Comment: Of koz I know, but I dont get why P is in the brackets %(

Answer (score 0):

short and simple:

```
int power(int base, int n)
```

thats where u get `n`, it comes as a parameter,

```
int p;
for (p = 1; n > 0; --n)
```

`p` is used as a sum, to calculate the result, it isn't used in calculating cycle steps, we can rewrite these 2 lines like this:

```
int p = 1;
for(; n > 0; --n)
```

from here it should be obvious that `p` doesn't influence cycle counter

```
for(; n > 0; --n)
```

and now you should understand that cycle runs while `n` is bigger than `0` that's the condition of the cycle, once this statement becomes `false`, cycle will stop, and on each step `n` is decremented, so cycle will run `n` times.

```
p = p * base;
```

and as you see here `p` is used just for calculating the power of base (method calculates how much is `base^n`), and the result is stored in `p`

Comment: i like your answer!  as I asked before "what for we need "p" in brackets, you cleared the issue, answering that we can omit it.